# Mysql, AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

Вопрос такой, я создаю таблицу в нем будет

```
CREATE TABLE members(
    -> id INT(9) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> name VARCHAR(20),
    -> last_name VARCHAR(30),
    -> email VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
    -> password VARCHAR(30),
    -> INDEX(id);
```

теперь сам вопрос, нужен ли столбцу `id` индекс или AUTO_INCREMENT само сделает как PRIMARY KEY

P.S может лучше будет убрать PRIMARY KEY из `email` и добавить к id , а email-и проверять если нету такого добавлять + index?

Comment: попытался найди в интернете но только нашел что для PRIMARY KEY не нужно создавать индекс оно автоматически создается, а про AUTO_INCREMENT не нашел

Comment: на id PRIMARY KEY и AUTO_INCREMENT. На email UNIQUE

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос оставлю открытым, интересно узнать нужен ли индекс или нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индекс нужен. Не обязательно первичный.

[MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html): для определения следующего значения счётчика автоинкремента использует индекс, в котором (если он составной) поле с автоинкрементом идёт первым по очереди:

> If the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of multiple indexes, MySQL
>   generates sequence values using the index that begins with the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column ..

[InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html): автоинкремент может быть применён только к полю которое является частью индекса. Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос (как же вы читали документацию?!):

> To use the AUTO_INCREMENT mechanism with an InnoDB table, an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column must be defined as part of an index ..